# Updating a map field in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm newbie and just starting coding a couple of months ago. I'm creating an app with react native with expo and I'm having trouble updating a map field into the document. So far, when I needed to update a filed(for example a name) I was doing the following:

```
const updateData = async () => {
        await updateDoc(doc(db,"users",uid),{
            name:name, 
            age: age,
        })
```

The problem is that I now have a map field which stores data in the following way:

The way that I have the app set-up, is that I have an array for the food items:

[image]

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([
        {Food: 'tomato', Calories: 20, Quantity: 1,},
        {Food: 'lettuce', Calories: 10, Quantity: 1,},
    ]);
```

and I would like to store it into a map field in the firestore document.

I thought that I would be able to use a for loop, so that I can populate each field of an array element into the map, but it seems that I'm unable to use a loop inside the await.

Is there like a workaround that I would be able to use in this case?

The for loop that is being highlighted in red:

```
        await updateDoc(doc(db,"user",uid),{
        for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            
        }

    },
    { merge: true })
```

Comment: Where is the key `fooditem1` coming from? Also can you share your 'for loop' code that you've tried?

Comment: I updated the main post with the for loop, here is a screenshot of it being highlighted in red in VSCode -https://prnt.sc/zqa-p05Sj9hW. As for the key, I'm unsure how can I add that. The example I showed is how I would like to store the data in the document and I've added that directly through the UI

Comment: Is there any reason to store that as a map? Like it'll be better to use 'food' as the key then, at least it'll be easier to query or update any specific food later. Also what is `breakfastFood` here?  That's something new in updated question.

Comment: I want to store that as a map because the document would store all of the food items that a users has eaten during the day and each food item will have it's own name, calories and quantity. Also, sorry for the breakfastFood, I changed it

Comment: I've posted an answer. Using food name as key might help to query docs or update a single food item's quantity or so later perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the array into a map, try using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as shown below:

```
const updatedMap = item.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.Food] = b;
  return a; 
}, {})

await updateDoc(doc(db, "user", uid), { food: updatedMap })
```

This will use food name as key in food map and test of the object as value.